# How to get 2 specific data from firebase using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to work on this code example I found online. I want to display the name and email welcome page after I log in but it doesn't show the name only the E-mail

This is the firebasehelper

```
public static async Task<List<Citizen>> GetAllCitizen()
        {
            try
            {
                var citizenlist = (await firebase
                    .Child("Citizen").OnceAsync<Citizen>()).Select(item =>
                new Citizen
                {
                    Email = item.Object.Email,
                    Password = item.Object.Password,
                    FirstName= item.Object.FirstName
                           
                }).ToList();
                return citizenlist;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
                return null;
            }
        }
        //Read     
        public static async Task<Citizen> GetCitizen(string email, string firstName)
        {
            try
            {
                var allCitizen = await GetAllCitizen();
                await firebase.Child("Citizen")
                .OnceAsync<Citizen>();
                return allCitizen.Where(a => a.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This is the WelcomeVM

```
public class WelcomeVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public WelcomeVM(string email2, string firstName2)
            {
                FirstName = firstName2;
               Email = email2;
            }

            private string firstName;
            public string FirstName
            {
                get { return firstName; }
                set { firstName = value; }
            }
        private string email;

        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
        private string password;

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

The welcome xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName, StringFormat='Welcome {0}'}" Margin="10" FontSize="25"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Email, StringFormat='Welcome {0}'}" Margin="10" FontSize="20"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName, StringFormat='Welcome {0}'}" Margin="10" FontSize="20"/>
```

I copied the code that displays the E-mail but it doesn't show the name only the E-mail

Comment: are you sure that the db contains a `FirstName` property and has data?

Comment: Yes  but when I run the app it only shows the Email "Welcome, test123@gmail.com" but the FirstName only shows" Welcome, "

Comment: Have you used PropertyChanged in setter method?

Comment: You need to identify where the problem is occurring.  Is it a problem with the db?  Or the query that returns the data?  Or the UI that displays the data?  You can’t fix the problem until you know what’s causing it.  That’s what debugging is all about.